# How to calculate rate of carbon dioxide from rate equation?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, kinetics, rate-equation

The concentration of carbon dioxide that changes with time:

$$\ce{CO2(g) + H2O(l) <=>[$k_\mathrm{fwd}$][$k_\mathrm{rev}$] HCO3-(aq) + H+(aq)}$$

How to calculate the integral for the following rate equation of carbon dioxide production?

$$\frac{\mathrm d[\ce{CO2}]}{\mathrm dt} = k_\mathrm{rev}[\ce{H+}][\ce{HCO3-}] - k_\mathrm{fwd}[\ce{CO2}]$$

Water is ignored in the rate equation due to its very large concentration that doesn't change over time.

Comment: Do you neglect the rate CO2(aq)+H2O <=> H2CO3(l)? CO2(aq) alone is not acidic.

Comment: @Poutnik  H2CO3 hardly exists. Even if hydration and deprotonation aren't concerted, this step could be well omitted. On the other hand, shouldn't the equation be with OH- instead of water?

Comment: @Mithoron It does exist. The equilibrium constant and both kinetic constants for CO2(aq)<>H2CO3 are known.

Comment: There is one reaction pathway from CO2(aq)<>H2CO3 however this is instantaneous compared to this reaction. I am really just wondering how to find the integral rate law for the rate equation above.

Comment: The key is to use stoichiometry to write the concentrations of your two products in terms of the concentration of CO2. Now you have a single-variable differential equation in [CO2]. Since it is first order and autonomous (coefficients are time-independent), the resulting ODE can be solved analytically using methods that you can look up.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we start with $n$ moles of $\ce{CO2}$ for simplicity. Then, at any point during the reaction, we will have $n-V_\text{gas}[\ce{CO2}]$ moles of each of the products. This means we could write their concentrations as
$$[\ce{H+}]=[\ce{HCO3-}]=\frac{n-V_\text{gas}[\ce{CO2}]}{V_\text{liquid}}$$

With all the concentrations expressed in terms of $[\ce{CO2}]$, we can rewrite your rate equation as

$$\frac{\mathrm d[\ce{CO2}]}{\mathrm dt} = k_\mathrm{rev}\bigg(\frac{n-V_\text{gas}[\ce{CO2}]}{V_\text{liquid}}\bigg)^2 - k_\mathrm{fwd}[\ce{CO2}]=k_\mathrm{rev}\bigg(V_\text{ratio}^2[\ce{CO2}]^2-2nV_\text{ratio}[\ce{CO2}]+A\bigg) - k_\mathrm{fwd}[\ce{CO2}]$$

Where $A=(\frac{n}{V_\text{liquid}})^2$. Since this now only depends on a single variable and a few constants (the starting amount of $\ce{CO2}$ and the volume of each phase), it can be [readily integrated](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=f%27%28t%29%3DC*f%28t%29%5E2-B*f%28t%29%2BA) to solve for how $[\ce{CO2}]$ (and consequently $[\ce{HCO3-}]$ and $[\ce{H+}]$) vary over time.